I don't understand the last part of the paper "Group Theory and the Rubik’s Cube" by Janet Chen (final theorem leads to the conclusion of valid moves)
(link to paper)
I was trying to read through the paper a long time ago, I think I managed to understand the core math of the paper. However, I am still struggling to see wheat the missing knowledge gap I have to understand the last theorem 11.1 which is as follows:
"Theorem 11.1. A configuration $(σ, τ, x, y)$ is valid iff $sgn σ = sgn τ$,
$\sum_{}x_i ≡ 0 (mod 3), and \sum_{}y_i ≡
0 (mod 2) $".
I don't know how, based on the theorem proof, made the conclusion of the $\frac{1}{12}$ fraction (remarks 11.15).
"Earlier, we calculated that there were $2^{12}3^
88!12!$ possible configurations of the Rubik’s cube;
now, Theorem 11.1 tells us that only $\frac{1}{12}$ of those are valid. Of course, this means there are still more than
$4 × 10^{19}$ valid configurations, no small number!"
In other words, I just want to know how the theorem links to the final conclusion, I don't expect to understand right away but to be able to be guided to the knowledge required to make understand the properties of the theorem (maybe I need to learn more on modular arithmetic?) or if it is right there in the paper that I need to know the key part and follow by myself to be able to say "huh! it makes sense that the theorem proves that only $\frac{1}{12}$ of those are valid".

Welcome to MSE. Let me suggest that look at our guidelines for formatting and writing your question, where you'll find this: Don't force someone to click on an external link just to see or understand your question, it should be immediately visible after clicking on your title. I suggest that you edit your post to include enough mathematical details so that your question makes sense.

Nice paper by Janet Chen, by the way. Thanks for sharing.

You have three conditions for validity

$\text{sgn}(\sigma) = \text{sgn}(\tau) $
$\sum x_i \equiv 0 \mod 3$
$\sum y_i \equiv 0 \mod 2$

Note that these three conditions are independent.
The first one cuts the configuration space by $1/2$; of the four possibilities for $(\text{sgn}(\sigma),\text{sgn}(\tau))$ $$(+,+), (+,-), (-,+), (-,-)$$ only two of them satisfy the first condition.
The second one cuts the configuration space by $1/3$; of the three possibilities for $\sum x_i \mod 3$
$$0, 1, 2 $$
only one of them satisfies the second condition.
The third one cuts the configuration space by $1/2$; the argument is identical to that of the second.
Since these are independent conditions, their proportions can be multiplied, and thus only $1/2 \cdot 1/3 \cdot 1/2 = 1/12$ of the configurations are valid.
There is one additional assumption being made here, that the values referenced in the conditions are evenly distributed across all possibilities; I haven't read enough of this paper to be sure that this is the case, but it certainly seems to be at least roughly the case.
